# Replace all occurrences of string within a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a string within a form with the contents of an input field. The strings are placeholders, select fields and labels.

My script can handle the input fields but I am unsure how to change the other elements.

The idea is to replace all occurrences of "your dog" with the contents of #input_2_10.

```
$('#input_2_10').on('blur',function(){
    
    var myStr = $(this).val();
        
    $('form').find("input").each(function() {
        var sd = $(this).attr('placeholder').toLowerCase();  
        var newStr = sd.replace(/your dog/g, myStr);
        $(this).attr("placeholder", newStr );
    });
    
});
```

```
<form id="gform_2">
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text">
        <input id="input_2_10" placeholder="Your Dog's Name">
    </div>
    <div class="gfield">
        <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_select">
            <select class="large gfield_select">
                <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Your Dog's Gender</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <legend class="gfield_label">Is your dog spayed or neutered?</legend>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please include the relevant HTML in the question so we can create a working example of the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, please take another look at my updated question.